# GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Framebuffer is not complete or incompatible with command

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

i have made a 360 image viewer on unity and i am changing image texture dynamically using c# script , so its work fine on PC unity but when i run it on android device it say error below:

```
OPENGL NATIVE PLUG-IN ERROR: GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Framebuffer is not complete or incompatible with command
```

My code below

```
 IEnumerator registerFunc(WWW www)
{
    yield return www;
    if (www.error == null)
  //if(true)
    {
        Debug.Log("OK - CountTime");
        texturas = www.texture;
        www.Dispose();
        www = null;

       sphereMS.material.mainTexture = texturas;// here i am getting error
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("ERROR");
    }
}
```

So any one can help me out in this how i can solve it.Thanks!

Comment: I have few questions: 1.What's the image extension name? 2.What's the size of the image? 3.What happens when you remove `www.Dispose();`? 4.What's your Unity version?

Comment: extension is jpg and size is 1.36 mb and www.dispose i dont knw what is doing but if we remove also same thing hppn and unity version is 2017.1.0f3

Comment: When I said size, I actually meant the resolution. Also, please show how `sphereMS` is declared.

Comment: resolution is 9999x2429 and sphereMS is public varible to which i have assigned sphere using drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

> resolution is 9999x2429 and sphereMS is public variable to which i have
>   assigned sphere using drag and drop

That's the problem. 9999 is really big. The limit on most Android devices is about 2048. Anything above this is a problem unless you are running this on very high end and expensive Android device.

One thing to try is replace

```
texturas = www.texture;
```

with

```
texturas = new Texture2D(4, 4);
texturas.LoadImage(www.bytes);
```

The `LoadImage` function is used to load jpg/png image into a Texture. It might fail too due to the size of the image.

---

If `LoadImage` fails too then you should have different Texture resolution for each platform on your server. The Android platform should request for a lower resolution version of your Textures. Just keep reducing the Textures resolution until it stops crashing. 2048 resolution should be fine.

I suggest you read [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/563094/mobile-max-texture-size.html) post about texture size limit in Unity.

EDIT:

If you have changed the resolution to below 2048 and the problem is still there then this is a bug.

Install Unity 2017.2.0p1 or [2017.3.0b3](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta) to get the fix. Few people experience this with the google-cardboard plugin.

Comment: Thanks but i have used lower resolution images also same hppn with that

Comment: about limit one you might be wrong coz its 360 image n in android native code i am downloading this image and it working fine.coz whole 9999x2429 will not be render on screen once we hv to move camera to see other stuff

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is 360 image or not. Use 2048 texture and that should work.Also, please read the part of my answer where is says *"LoadImage"*. Try that too. Don't just make a comment without trying what's in the answer. You can doubt it but try it first before commenting

Comment: same thing LoadImage it got crash again :(

Comment: Even if i put static texture also it use to get crash y its happing i dont knw

Comment: The size of your image is 2048?

Comment: size is 139kb with 1081x255 px

Comment: can i get ur email or contact so that i can share my code with you i am stuck in this problem

Comment: I use to do that but can't because I won't be around my Android device until Monday. Check my update about this being a bug when using cardboard. Install Unity 2017.3.0b3 and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: Ok i will try to update new version of unity but when you get back please let me know

Comment: I am here. It's just that I don't have my Android device with me. I will get it back on Monday

Comment: i have searched on net it might be because of texture compression techniques which we use for android

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it happens on Android devices using Mali GPU, even Asphalt 8 couldn't run on these devices (at least old ones).

I tried on Huawei Mate 10 and Samsung Galaxy A50s, as both are using Mali-G72 MP12 and MP3 respectively so getting the same error and the image gets black/blank (couldn't render).

While same works fine on other Android and iOS devices

Answer (score -1):

use parametre

```
-disable-gpu
```

or

> app.disableHardwareAcceleration()

look here
[enter link description here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appdisablehardwareacceleration)

Comment: The question is about Unity and Android, this appears to be instructions related to Electron. Are you sure you're answering the right question?

Comment: oui j'avais  la meme erreur sur mon raspberry pi3  acceleration opengl me pose cette erreur a l'execution de myapps crée avec qt5  alors "   /.myapp -platform eglfs -disable-gpu "